# 2x10 amp = 20 amp?

Tags: led, transformer

I have a pretty simple setup, but i have a problem, that i what to solve the simple way.

I have buy a led bar supposed to be for truck but i will get it inside to light up a big wall here is the bar with the specs : [Simplive® 42 inch 240w Led Work Light Bar Flood Spot Combo Beam Driving Lights Fog Lamp Off Road Lighting for Suv Ute Atv Truck 4x4 Boat with Mounts.](https://www.amazon.ca/gp/product/B00WLZFRCI/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o01_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1)

this bar is for 12v, 240 watt. so with little calculation it must use a 100v to 12v 20 amp ? right.... if the calculation is right so i need a tranformer that get me 12v 20amp, it's quite expensive, i just cannot get a 100$ transfo for a 100$ led bar....

so my question : can i buy this transformer (10$) [110v to 12v 10 amp](https://www.amazon.ca/12Vmonster%C2%AE-100V-120V-Halogen-voltage-transformer/dp/B00ALU0T6Y/ref=pd_sim_sbs_469_7?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1&refRID=R1Q2V0HC7YFR9AB45CD0) and to get the require 20amp i will get 2 of these, wire in paralle, to get 10a+10a=20A...

is it ok, can it be made, will it work ? any other suggestions ?

note, i have search harder and found [this 12v 20amp for a good price](https://www.amazon.ca/JOYLAND-Switching-Supply-Transformer-output/dp/B019OLHDJQ/ref=sr_1_4?s=hi&ie=UTF8&qid=1479616555&sr=1-4&keywords=110v%20to%2012%20v%20240w), maybe it simpler, but that does not answer my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The light bar operates from 10 - 30 Volt DC, so you need a DC power supply.

The Halogen light transformer in your first link outputs AC, so cannot be used with this light bar.

Look for "LED power supply" or "DC power supply" rather than "Transformer".  The "12 volt 20 amp" unit in your final link looks suitable.

Comment: I have order the latest 20A 12v as you told me.... the forst tranformer was absolutely ans error... thanks to point it ! my wrong !

Answer (score 1):

The specs say that the light bar operates on "10-30V"  You can use lower current if you use a higher voltage.  I found many 240W power supplies for sale like 12V @ 18A or 24V @ 10A for around US$35  And many 240W LED supplies on Ebay for $25~35. You can't expect to get a 240W power supply for nothing.  If you want to avoid buying an expensive power supply, then get a light bar that operates on mains power.

Comment: Led bar that operate on 110v main power WILL BE A DREAM... never seen this before. any amazon.ca of link to get me this marvel ?